# Issues with Pipelining in sklearn

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am brand new to sklearn. I am using Pipeline to use Vectorizer and Classifier together in a Text mining problem. Here is my code:

```
def create_ngram_model():
tfidf_ngrams = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 3),
analyzer="word", binary=False)
clf = GaussianNB()
pipeline = Pipeline([('vect', tfidf_ngrams), ('clf', clf)])
return pipeline


def get_trains():
    data=open('../cleaning data/cleaning the sentences/cleaned_comments.csv','r').readlines()[1:]
    lines=len(data)
    features_train=[]
    labels_train=[]
    for i in range(lines):
        l=data[i].split(',')
        labels_train+=[int(l[0])]
        a=l[2]
        features_train+=[a]
    return features_train,labels_train

def train_model(clf_factory,features_train,labels_train):
    features_train,labels_train=get_trains()
    features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(features_train, labels_train, test_size=0.1, random_state=42)
    clf=clf_factory()
    clf.fit(features_train,labels_train)
    pred = clf.predict(features_test)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(pred,labels_test)
    return accuracy

X,Y=get_trains()
print train_model(create_ngram_model,X,Y)
```

The features returned from get_trains() are strings.
I am getting this error.

```
clf.fit(features_train,labels_train)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 130, in fit
    self.steps[-1][-1].fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 149, in fit
    X, y = check_arrays(X, y, sparse_format='dense')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 263, in check_arrays
    raise TypeError('A sparse matrix was passed, but dense '
TypeError: A sparse matrix was passed, but dense data is required. Use X.toarray() to convert to a dense numpy array.
```

I have come across this error many times. Then, I just changed the features to features_transformed.toarray() but since, here, I am using pipeline I am not able to do so as the transformed feature is returned automatically. I also tried making a new class which returns the features_transformed.toarray() but that too throwed the same error.
I have searched a lot but not getting it. Please help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options:

1. Use sparse-data-compatible classifier. For example, documentation says [Bernoulli Naive Bayes](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.BernoulliNB) and [Multinomial Naive Bayes](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html#sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB) support sparse input for `fit`.
2. Add a "densifier" to the Pipeline. Apparently, you got it wrong, this one worked for me (when I needed to densify my sparse data along the way):

   ```
   class Densifier(object):
       def fit(self, X, y=None):
           pass
       def fit_transform(self, X, y=None):
           return self.transform(X)
       def transform(self, X, y=None):
           return X.toarray()
   ```

   Make sure to put into pipeline it right before classificator.

Comment: Hi, I have changed my pipeline to pipeline = Pipeline([('vect', tfidf_ngrams), ('densify',Densifier), ('clf', clf)]). It's still giving error- Xt = transform.fit_transform(Xt, y, **fit_params_steps[name])
TypeError: unbound method fit_transform() must be called with Densifier instance as first argument (got csr_matrix instance instead)

Comment: @user2443048, which error? Now you broke your pipeline by including class instead of instance (an object). Replace `Densifier` by `Densifier()`

Comment: It's now giving Memory error. I think, i should use SelectPercentile to select 10-20% best features, but actually don't exactly know how can i couple it with the pipeline.

Comment: `SelectPercentile` does not work with sparse data (according to the documentation).

Comment: Ah, it worked. I just selected 5% of the features and added it to the pipeline before densifier. Thanks.

Comment: New error now. Started GridSearchCV. It's throwing this error.             for key, value in six.iteritems(step.get_params(deep=True)):
AttributeError: 'Densifier' object has no attribute 'get_params'

Comment: Inherit `Densifier` class from [BaseEstimator](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.BaseEstimator.html#sklearn.base.BaseEstimator)

Comment: I would really rather go with something that supports sparse features, like LinearSVC or MultinomialNB. Why do you want to use a Gaussian NB for text data?